# Struct has two fields , each one is an 1d array. Passing the struct object to a function without pointer , would change the struct object?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

This is a question from a test that i had yesterday.
Considering this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARR_SIZE 5

typedef struct _A {
   int _arr1[ARR_SIZE];
   int* _arr2; } A;

void foo(A a) {
   int i;
   for (i=0;i< ARR_SIZE;++i)
      a._arr1[i] = 5*i;
}

void bar(A a) {
   int i;
   for (i=0;i< ARR_SIZE;++i)
   a._arr2[i] = 10*i;
}

void printA(A* a,char* str)
{
   int i;
   printf("%s:\n_arr1:\t",str);
   for (i=0;i< ARR_SIZE;++i)
       printf("%d\t",a->_arr1[i]);
       printf("\n_arr2:\t");
   for (i=0;i< ARR_SIZE;++i)
       printf("%d\t",a->_arr2[i]);
       printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    A a1 = {{1,2,3,4,5},0};
    A a2 = a1;
    a1._arr2 = a1._arr1;
    a2._arr2 = a2._arr1;
    foo(a1);
    bar(a2);
    printA(&a1,"a1");
    printA(&a2,"a2");
    return 0;
}
```

Now, it print this: 
`a1:

_arr1:  1       2       3       4       5

_arr2:  1       2       3       4       5

a2:

_arr1:  0       10      20      30      40

_arr2:  0       10      20      30      40`

I don't understand the printings. If i make step by step configuring the code, i see that passing `a1` to `foo` won't make anything because i didn't sent a pointer-to-`a1`. But what i don't understand is why if i sent `a2` to `bar` without a pointer, it changes `a2`.
I thought about because `_arr2` is a pointer, and because of it,`bar` changes it, so `a2` changes. But, we know that every array is a pointer to the first element. So `_arr1` is an array, so it a pointer, but doesn't change!

Can someone explain me why it happens? tnx a lot in advance!

Comment: Arrays are not pointers.

Comment: when you don't pass struct by pointers, you will have an implicit copy of it. in you example, `bar` modify the array through a pointer, that's why.

Comment: and arrays are not pointers semantically, but they can be the same in type system. two are different concepts. `int a[10], b[10]; a = b;` is illegal assignment.

Comment: I can only hope the instructor is not teaching their students to write names with leading underscores '_' and to write #define'd values that are not surrounded by parens '(' and ')' and writing multiple indented lines under an 'if' statement with out using braces '{' and '}' and using meaningless variable names like 'A'

Comment: passing the whole struct rather than a pointer to the struct is a very bad idea because the compiler will introduce 1) 'hidden' memory areas (that cannot be otherwise reached), 2) at least 2 calls to memcpy() for each struct,  This greatly increases the complexity of the code, is much more difficult to debug, even with a good debugger and hides what is actually occuring.

Comment: When passing the struct, the whole struct is passed, including any data within the struct, so the contents of arr1 are available/copied, while the pointer to array arr2 gets the pointer passed, but the data being pointed to does not get copied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the changes done by `bar` are visible in the original `struct` is because `_arr2` in the copy of the `struct` is still pointing to `_arr1` of the original `struct` that you have passed. Essentially, you are passing a pointer, except now it is hidden in the `struct` that is passed by value.

[image: Illustration]

Here is a way to see what's going on:

```
void bar(A a) {
    printf("%p %p", (void*)a._arr2, (void*)&a._arr1);
    for (int i=0;i< ARR_SIZE;++i) {
       a._arr2[i] = 10*i;
    }
}
```

This will print different pointers for `_arr2` stored in the `struct` and `_arr1` embedded in it.

Answer (score 2):

`struct A` has an array and a pointer inside.

```
typedef struct _A {
   int _arr1[ARR_SIZE];     // _arr1 is an array
   int* _arr2; } A;         // _arr2 is a pointer
```

If you pass a copy of the pointer, the copy still points to the same place.

Changing what the copy points to reflects in the calling function.

You might like to read about differences between arrays and pointers.
I suggest section 6 of the [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/).